# AT-SPI in Upstart

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have created an application that get informations of firefox using AT-SPI and c++ and worked.
But it doesn't work while runs as upstart not an application despite the same source code.

The reason is atspi_init() returns error 2.

I wrote the conf file of upstart like this:

```
description "firefoxurl daemon"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on  runlevel [!2345]

script
    exec /opt/GetCurrentUrlOfFirefox
end script
```

Can someone tell me why AT_SPI did not work in Upstart?

Answer (score 0):

If it expects Firefox to be running, that's obviously a false assumption during system startup.

You should probably be looking at running it from the user's X startup scripts; and even then, Firefox will usually not start until some time later.